# Set first element of AJAX response as selected value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm fairly new to JS so I'm sure there's an easy way to do this.

I'm attempting to create a dropdown menu from the first element of an AJAX response. The response looks like this:

```
[0: "14Z18Oct2017", 1: "13Z18Oct2017", 2: "12Z18Oct2017", ... 14: "00Z18Oct2017"]
```

I've populated the dropdown menu without issue, but on the pageload, I'd like to select the first element of the dropdown as the default (which will be used to dynamically display images within the directory).

I'm using [HAniS](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/hanis/), an HTML image animating webapp to piece together the images in the directories of the AJAX response. HAniS requires a path to the images, which I've put at the bottom of the get_config() function.

Here's what I have so far:

**config.js**

```
function get_config() {
    var basepath = "http://site/times/";
    $.ajax({
        url: '../times.php', //a php script echoing an array of directory contents
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(dirs) {
            $.each(dirs, function(index, date) {
                $('#times').append($('<option></option>').val(date).html(date));
            }
        }
    })
    // Here's part of the config JSON that HAniS requires
    var hancon = {
        // image_only_base should be:
        //     "http://site/times/14Z18Oct2017/" -> basepath + first element of response
        image_only_base: basepath + $('#times').val()
        // this is where I'm lost
    }
};
```

**index.html**

```
<body onload="get_config()">
    <div id="testing">
        <select id="times">
            <!-- the options here are created via AJAX -->
            <!-- need the first value listed to be selected by default -->
            <option value="14Z18Oct2017">14Z18Oct2017</option>
            <option value="13Z18Oct2017">14Z18Oct2017</option>
            <...>
            <option value="00Z18Oct2017">14Z18Oct2017</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

I think the last line of the get_config() function is the problem.

I took a stab at it with `$('#times').val()`, but no value is returned here.

I've also tried:

```
$('#times').val(1),
$('#times').val(0),
$("#times option:selected").val()
```

and a few others.

How can I reference the first element of the dropdown to dynamically create the path? (the contents of the response will be constantly changing - a continuous python script is adding more directories to the path)

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Where does `dates` come from, your success function's parameter is called `dirs`.  Anyway assuming you have `success: function(dates) {` then the first one would be `dates[0]`, so after you have populated the dropdown you can set its value to the value of dates[0].

Comment: @James    Sorry about that, got messed up in my transcription. Fixing it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `.attr('selected', 'selected');` to select an option;
2. Initialize your image library in the success of ajax request as it is asynchronous.

**Like**

```
  function get_config() {
    var basepath = "http://site/times/";
    $.ajax({
        url: '../times.php', //a php script echoing an array of directory contents
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(dirs) {
          $.each(dates, function(index, date) {
              $el = $('<option></option>').val(date).html(date);
              if (index === 0)
                $el = $el.attr("selected", "selected");
              $('#times').append($el);
            }

            // Here's part of the config JSON that HAniS requires
            var hancon = {
              // image_only_base should be:
              //     "http://site/times/14Z18Oct2017/" -> basepath + first element of response
              image_only_base: basepath + $('#times').val()
              // this is where I'm lost
            }
          }
        })

    };
```

Comment: Good answer, but use `if (index === 0)`.  A lot of things that are not the int 0 can match `index == 0`.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense, but `$("#times").val()` is returning undefined to the console. I tried `$("#times").attr("selected")` but that doesn't work either. What do I use?

Comment: Where are you doing `console.log` ? You should do it inside the success callback and after setting all the options.

Comment: @void okay it works when I put the console log in the success callback, but I need to add it to the image_only_base in the config variable. That's where I originally had it. Should I just set it as a variable in the success callback?

Comment: Check my code where i have put the object `hancon` and use it there only. And if my answer solves your originally asked question then please mark it correct.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    function get_config() {
        var basepath = "http://site/times/";
        var hancon; // Global variable that will update each time when select
        // If you update hancon befor getting data from server it will be 
    undefined.
        $.ajax({
            url: 'GetTimes', //a php script echoing an array of directory contents
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (dates) { // variable which you get from "success" and in "$.each" should be same.
                var sel = $("#times");
                $.each(dates, function (index, date) {
                    $el = $('<option></option>').val(date).html(date);
                    if (index === 0)
                        $el = $el.attr("selected", "selected");
                    $('#times').append($el);
                });
                updateHancon(); // You need to update Hancon in success so when it will get data
                //it will update otherwise it will be undefinded.

            }
        })

        function updateHancon() { // Best practise to create function and call it instead putting all in one function.
            hancon = {
                // image_only_base should be:
                //     "http://site/times/14Z18Oct2017/" -> basepath + first element of response
                image_only_base: basepath + $('#times').val()
                // this is where I'm lost
            }
            console.log(hancon);
        }

        // Update chnage event of "Times" for the and call updateHancon function for updating hancon
    };
</script>
```